# How can you use split with a regex that's stored in a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby, can I split like this?

```
my_string = "/(ice cold)|cold/"

"It is ice cold outside.".split(my_string)
#=> ["It is ", " outside"]

"It is cold outside.".split(my_string)
#=> ["It is ", " outside"]
```

2) What should be the regex to get the same outputs as above?

thanks!

Comment: _"with a regex that's stored in a variable"_ – there's no regex in that variable. It's a string representation of a regex literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split_pattern = /ice cold|cold/`
Will match for 'ice cold' and 'cold'

I have omitted the `()` around ice cold, as that will not split AND remove the "ice cold" string from the array. While omitting it will.

```
s1 = "it is ice cold outside"
s1.split(split_pattern)
#=> ["it is ", " outside"]
```

```
s2 = "it is cold outside"
s2.split(split_pattern)
#=> ["it is ", " outside"]
```

Comment: While, if you put parens around `ice cold` as the OP has it, it will not.

Comment: :P Thanks :D I will update the answer with that clarification :D

Comment: You should also change the variable name. Assigning a regex to a variable called `my_string` is a bit misleading.